# can symfony 2.8 updated with twig 2.4.4?

Tags: twig, symfony-2.8

Currently the application have symfony 2.8.42 and twig version 1.35.3.
Due to some security issue in twig we need to upgrade twig to 2.4.4 and above. But I am not sure as what else will be broken once I update the twig version ? 
I cannot find anywhere for symfony 2.8 compatible twig versions or vice versa.

Can someone help me with the compatible version and what are the things that will break if I update twig to 2.4.4 ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested myself by updating and was able to update to twig 2.4.4 without any issues. Changes the composer.lock file for the same and did the composer install again, the new twig version as created successfully.